# Sonata how make autocomplete filter on current entity property

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, autocomplete, sonata-admin

I'm working on a sf2 project using Sonata Admin Bundle.
The project is a Donations website for humanitarian mission.
I have a 'Personne' entity, represent benefactors (donation makers).

My problem is the following: 
I have to filter results in the sonata list view using autocompletion.
I want filter results using the 'name' property of the current entity ('Personne').

What I'm expecting :

```
$datagridMapper
    ->add('personne', 'doctrine_orm_model_autocomplete', 
          array('label' => 'AutoComplete'), 
          null, 
          array('property' => 'name'))

// error output : " The option `association_mapping` must be set for field: `personne` "
```

You can see my full admin class and entity on this gist :
https://gist.github.com/chalasr/0658a02b1c04180f5563

I understand this field type is reserved to entity associations (by example I already use it for filter results of my Donation entity by Personne name (other admin class).

My question is : 
Is it possible to do what I need ?
If I can't do that using this field type, what is the right way to achieve this task ?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: I really does not seem to be possible yet. I added a FR on github: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3172 - btw: you should link your github profile on your twitter profile! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonctionnality is now bundled with Sonata as simple as:

```
$filter->add('label', ModelFilter::class, ['field_type'=>ModelAutocompleteType::class,'field_options' => ['property' => 'name']])
```

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of tests, it seems this functionality isn't yet provided by Sonata.

So, I had build an homemade autocomplete method in my admin controller and used it as ajax in my overridden CRUD:list.html.twig template.
This method takes field name, other autocomplete fields values, and keyword as parameters and reload results on keyup event.

You can look on this gist:
https://gist.github.com/chalasr/5c27ae64dc596967f18a

If you have an idea/proposition for optimize my code (simple autocomplete field type for $formMapper ?), I'm really interested.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's possible to make a choice field and use integrated select2 to handle autocomplete, I don't know how well it would fare with large tables though.

```
    $datagridMapper
            ->add('personne','doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'callback' => array($this, 'filterByName'),
            'field_type' => 'text',
             ), 'entity',array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Personne',
                'choice_label' => 'name'
                    ))
```

We add `'doctrine_orm_callback'` because regular string filter can't handle EntityType Field, so we need to do it ourselves.

```
public function filterByName($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
{
       if (!$value['value']) {
        return;
        }   

        $queryBuilder
                ->andWhere($alias . '.name' . ' = ' . ':name' )
                ->setParameter('name' , $value['value']->getName());

        return true;
}
```

1 more thing, select2 won't create autocomplete (search) box if dropdown box has less than 10 choices, because it's set up in Admin.js that way.

> ```
>             select.select2({
>                 width: function(){
>                     // Select2 v3 and v4 BC. If window.Select2 is defined, then the v3 is installed.
>                     // NEXT_MAJOR: Remove Select2 v3 support.
>                     return Admin.get_select2_width(window.Select2 ? this.element : jQuery(this));
>                 },
>                 dropdownAutoWidth: true,
>                 minimumResultsForSearch: 10,
>                 allowClear: allowClearEnabled
>             });
> ```

so you need to override it, if you want that to be less.